# How to Access .txt file from Assert folder in native c?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have unable to access a .txt file from Assert folder in C using NDK. 
Do anyone have an Idea how do I access the file from my C file.

```
public class HelloJni extends AppCompatActivity {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }
    private AssetManager mgr;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_jni);
        mgr = getResources().getAssets();
        stringFromJNI(mgr);

    }
    public native String  stringFromJNI(AssetManager mgr);

}
```

In Hello-jni.c file I need to access the .txt

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_inspiringlife_fido_HelloJni_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz, jobject assetManager )
{
    //access .txt file from assert folder 
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello JNI ");
}
```

Comment: Currently i am able to access the Assert folder but unable to access the file from assert folder

Answer (score 0):

```
AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
assert(NULL != mgr);

AAsset* testAsset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, "hello.txt", AASSET_MODE_UNKNOWN);
if (testAsset)
{
    assert(testAsset);

    size_t assetLength = AAsset_getLength(testAsset);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "!!!!Native Audio", "Asset file size: %d\n", assetLength);

    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(assetLength + 1);
    AAsset_read(testAsset, buffer, assetLength);
    buffer[assetLength] = 0;

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "!!!!!Test Asset Manager", "The value is %s", buffer);

    AAsset_close(testAsset);
    free(buffer);
}
else
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "!!!!!Test Asset Manager", "Cannot open file");
}

//rsa_gen_keys(pub, priv);
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "!!!Hello from JNI");
```

Now I am able to read the file from assert file.